# Itextsharp open password protected file modify it and adopt protection

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I open an existing pdf. Checking for protection and ask for password if it is protected and open it with:

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        Stream outputStream = null;
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;

        try
        {
            pdfReader = GetPdfReaderObject();
            outputStream = new FileStream(filePathDestination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream);

                PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("watermark", pdfStamper.Writer);

                for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++) {
                    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex);
                    PdfContentByte pdfData = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageIndex);

                    pdfData.BeginLayer(layer);

                    PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
                    graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.5F;
                    pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
                    pdfData.BeginText();

                    iTextSharp.text.Image watermarkImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(watermarkImagePath), ImageFormat.Png);

                    float width = pageRectangle.Width;
                    float height = pageRectangle.Height;

                    watermarkImage.SetAbsolutePosition(width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2, height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);

                    pdfData.AddImage(watermarkImage);
                    pdfData.EndText();
                    pdfData.EndLayer();
                }
            }
            pdfStamper.Close();
            outputStream.Close();
            outputStream.Dispose();
            pdfReader.Close();
            pdfReader.Dispose();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ....
        }
    }
```

After my modifications I save it but the protection is destroyed.

Why the protection is destroyed?
How can I save the protection from the origin document und add it to my modified one.

Regards

Comment: Please provide more code. You don't show your way of modifying your PDF. Do you use a `PdfStamper`? Or a `PdfCopy`? Or a `PdfWriter`? And how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `PdfStamper` to manipulate an existing PDF.

**For any source PDF:** If you want the result to be encrypted, you may use the `SetEncryption` method appropriately.

Have a look at the  [EncryptionPdf.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter12&ex=EncryptionPdf), especially its method `EncryptPdf`:

```
PdfReader reader = ...;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
    {
        stamper.SetEncryption(
                USER, OWNER, 
                PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, 
                PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA
        );
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Here `USER` and `OWNER` are the user and owner passwords of your choice. You might want to use a different set of permissions.

**For already encrypted source PDFs** you may alternatively choose to use the `PdfStamper` in append mode (i.e. use a `PdfStamper` constructor with a `bool append` parameter set to `true`). In that case the original encryption will also be applied to the updated PDF.

Comment: With the append flag the protection/encryption is also working after modification. But if I opeb the pdf with Acrobat Reader it tells me that: "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not Display the page correctly. Please contact the Person who created the PDF document to correct the Problem". Do I need to encrypt my new added image also? Are what is the problem? On an document with no encryption it's working without failure.

Comment: @GermanSniper Could you provide a sample, both before and after manipulation?

Comment: I will provide some sample files later. But one more Problem occours: If I add the tag append I can't remove content from the pdf's. How can I save encryption, delete and add content? Slowly i'm going crazy...

Comment: An alternative to using append mode is using the *unethical* mode, cf. the discussion under @Bruno's answer. Simply set the static `bool PdfReader.unethicalreading` to `true` and use your `PdfStamper` without append mode.

Comment: Here the two sample files with error. I hope u can help me with These. [Sample pdf with error](http://www.file-upload.net/gal-61870/ryg9jw/1.html)

Comment: I'll look at them later, i don't have my tools available right now.

Comment: @GermanSniper Ok, I looked at your files (BTW, that file service is quite a pain).The manipulated PDF is not encrypted anymore. Which of the proposed methods did you use to create this PDF? `append`? `unethicalreading`? Explicit separate encryption?

Comment: oh sry. The files was modified without copy the encryption. Here is an example with encryption. [sample 2 with unethicalreading](http://www.file-upload.net/gal-62249/cyda/1.html) . But always if the source document is encrypted I got an error in my modified pdf document opening with acrobat

Comment: Ok I solve the Problem with the pdf invalide Content stream. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235339/pdf-generated-with-itext-becomes-corrupted-when-using-setsimplecolumn  THX for your help!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Which version of iText are you using?

When a password protected PDF was opened using the `owner` password and manipulated by `PdfStamper`, all original password protection was indeed removed. This changed in iText 5.3.5. See the [changelog](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/535):

> Important: we now keep the original owner password when stamping a document.

In other words: with all iText versions prior to 5.3.5, the owner password is lost. Starting with 5.3.5, it should be kept.

Comment: I use version 5.4.3. That can't be the problem

Comment: *we now keep the original owner password when stamping a document* - Always? I find a `if (reader.isEncrypted() && (append || PdfReader.unethicalreading)) { crypto = new PdfEncryption(reader.getDecrypt()); }` in the `PdfStamperImp` code which looks like keeping it only in append or unethical mode...

Comment: Hmm... I wrote that code. Now that you remind me of unethical mode, I remember: if you know the owner password, you're probably supposed to set the password with `stamper.setEncryption()`. If we automatically reuse the existing password, there's no way to decrypt a document into an unencrypted PDF (which is also a use-case). I gave an up-vote to your answer (and I also up-voted the question as it's a good one).

Comment: If i remember Correctly, the check-in comment for adding conditions other than `isEncrypted` was that this made decrypting using the stamper impossible. ;)